# Получение представления для сочетания клавиш

Tags: awt, java

Допустим, у меня в приложении есть контрол, имеющий какой-либо `KeyStroke`. И у него автоматически выставляется `ToolTip` в зависимости от системы. Например, на Windows это текст вида `Ctrl+Shift+Z`, а на MacOS - `⌘⇧Z`. Как получить эту строку для заданного сочетания клавиш?

P.S.
Интересует получение данной строки как с помощью AWT (или Swing).

Comment: у твоем приложении автоматически выставляется хот кей? я правильно понял?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрие в сторону [KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyModifiersText(int)), [KeyEvent.getKeyText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText(int)) и [KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersExText](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiersExText%28int%29)